# Wierd parse error --The server tag is not well formed

Tags: asp.net, parsing

I am in a bit of a jam I have been trying to figure out what is wrong with this for ages, it was working before then it suddenly stopped. Error I am getting is:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   Parser Error 
>    Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.
>
> Source Error:

```
Line 20:            <tr>
Line 21:               <td width="200" valign="top" align="center">
Line 22:                  <img id="imageShow"  runat="server" src="<%#  DataBinder.Eval(  Container.DataItem, "Link" ) %><%# DataBinder.Eval( Container.DataItem, "ImageName")%>" width="200px" height="150px" onclick ="ShowImage" alt="already done" />
Line 23:               </td>
Line 24:              <td width="200">
```

Source File:  /WebForm1.aspx    Line:  22

my code looks like this:

```
<asp:Panel id="pnlShowItems" runat="server">
<asp:DataList id="d1Items" runat="server" DataKeyField="ImageID" >
 <ItemTemplate>
 <table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
       <tr>
          <td width="200" valign="top" align="center">
           <img id="imageShow"  runat="server" 
src="<%# DataBinder.Eval(  Container.DataItem, "Link" ) %><
%# DataBinder.Eval( Container.DataItem, "ImageName")%>" width="200px" height="150px"
 onclick ="ShowImage" alt="already done" />
          </td>
         <td width="200">
            <strong><%#  DataBinder.Eval(  Container.DataItem, "Link" ) %></strong>
          <br />
         Cost: $<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PageDetailID")%><br /><br />
<asp:Button id="btnAddToCart" runat="server"
                   Text="Add To Cart" CommandName="Edit"/>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td colspan="2" width="400"><hr height="1" />
           </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</ItemTemplate>
 </asp:DataList>
</asp:Panel>
```

and the code behind is like this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn;
        SqlCommand comm;
        SqlDataReader reader;

        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        comm = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT ImageID, RTRIM(LTRIM(ImageName ))  ImageName,    Description, 'Images/' Link,    PageDetailID FROM dbo.Images", conn);

        conn.Open();
        reader = comm.ExecuteReader();

        reader.Read();

        d1Items.DataSource = reader;
        d1Items.DataBind();


        conn.Close();

    }




    public void ShowImage() 
    {

        DataListItem dli = this.d1Items.Controls[this.d1Items.Controls.Count - 1] as DataListItem;
        Image img = dli.FindControl("imageShow") as Image;

        Image1.ImageUrl = img.ImageUrl;

    }
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: What's `Image1` in `Image1.ImageUrl = img.ImageUrl;` ?

Comment: Image1 is just an Image I was to show, after loading up the images I have binded. not sure why Image1 looks  like a class instead of an identifier

Comment: Anyone? may I please have some assistance?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here:

```
src=
   "<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Link") %>" +
   "<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ImageName")%>"
```

The problem is with the quotes nested inside quotes.

Notice how even StackOverflow's code formatting picks up on how "Link" and "ImageName" are a piece of code in that line.

Try replacing the double quotes with single quotes:

```
src=
   '<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Link") %>' +
   '<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ImageName")%>'
```

If this doesn't help you (old question), perhaps it will help others.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust your delegate - i suggest you to use `imageButton`

```
<asp:ImageButton
 id="imageShow"  
 runat="server" 
 ImageUrl="<%#  DataBinder.Eval(  Container.DataItem, "Link" ) + DataBinder.Eval( Container.DataItem,      "ImageName")%>" width="200px" height="150px" onclick ="ShowImage" alt="already done" />

void ShowImage(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{

}
```

Nota : the problem is with your delegate signature

Comment: I tried it didn't work, this driving me up the wall. Thanks though Aghilas Yakoub. Any other suggestions?